# How to skip commented lines in sipp xml file

Tags: sipp

I am trying to grep for a pattern in sipp xml file. That pattern might be commented in that file, it should skip the commented occurence and search for next occurence. Pattern : pcap    file : test.xml
As `<exec play_pcap_audio="MULAW_p40_song.pcap"/>` commented in xml file, it should return only `<exec play_pcap_audio="MULAW_p41_song.pcap"/>`

But I am getting

```
grep "pcap" test.xml
<exec play_pcap_audio="MULAW_p40_song.pcap"/>
<exec play_pcap_audio="MULAW_p41_song.pcap"/>
```

test.xml :

```
<!--
<nop>
  <action>
    <exec play_pcap_audio="MULAW_p40_song.pcap"/>
  </action>
</nop>
-->
<nop>
  <action>
    <exec play_pcap_audio="MULAW_p41_song.pcap"/>
  </action>
</nop>
```

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Is grep a hard requirement, or can it be replaced with something else (i.e. a dedicated xml-parsing library)? Grep is based on regex patterns, and regex is Not A Good Tool for parsing xml. That's not to say what you want can't be done, but it [won't be pretty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5166781).

Comment: grep can be replaced..not mandatory to use grep

Comment: can you please help me on this

Comment: which tool can be used for parsing sipp xml file?

Comment: Chris H - can u help on this

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for product recommendations. You can find an xml reader yourself, I'm sure you've heard of google.

Comment: Not asking for any product...just asking how to search for pattern in above case

Comment: I already told you, regular expressions are Bad At This. Any xml parsing tool will let you search a simple query like this. Find one and use it.